# Why does this query work in SQL management studio but not php through mssql?

Tags: php, sql-server

I use mssql on php 5.5.25 running on mac.

The query is

```
UPDATE Sessions SET
            UserID = 0,
            ClientIP = '127.0.0.1',
            TimeStamp = 1436465436,
            SessionData = 'a:1:{s:5:"forms";a:1:{s:26:"login_user_form-1436465436";O:4:"Form":15:{s:10:"*form_id";s:15:"login_user_form";s:9:"*gen_id";s:26:"login_user_form-1436465436";s:13:"*form_items";a:4:{s:8:"username";O:17:"FormItemTextField":22:{s:9:"*length";i:60;s:7:"*mask";s:0:"";s:13:"*input_type";s:6:"string";s:12:"*max_value";N;s:12:"*min_value";N;s:7:"*type";s:9:"textfield";s:7:"*name";s:8:"username";s:8:"*value";N;s:7:"*size";i:30;s:11:"*disabled";b:0;s:10:"*form_id";s:15:"login_user_form";s:8:"*print";b:1;s:8:"*label";s:8:"Username";s:14:"*placeholder";s:0:"";s:14:"*description";N;s:9:"*weight";i:0;s:9:"*parent";s:13:"primary_group";s:11:"*required";b:1;s:10:"*classes";a:0:{}s:9:"*dbname";s:8:"username";s:15:"*token_prefix";s:1:":";s:18:"*format_callback";b:0;}s:8:"password";O:16:"FormItemPassword":24:{s:13:"*min_length";i:0;s:13:"*validation";b:1;s:9:"*length";i:100;s:7:"*mask";s:0:"";s:13:"*input_type";s:6:"string";s:12:"*max_value";N;s:12:"*min_value";N;s:7:"*type";s:8:"password";s:7:"*name";s:8:"password";s:8:"*value";N;s:7:"*size";i:30;s:11:"*disabled";b:0;s:10:"*form_id";s:15:"login_user_form";s:8:"*print";b:1;s:8:"*label";s:8:"Password";s:14:"*placeholder";s:0:"";s:14:"*description";s:56:"I forgot my password.";s:9:"*weight";i:1;s:9:"*parent";s:13:"primary_group";s:11:"*required";b:1;s:10:"*classes";a:0:{}s:9:"*dbname";s:8:"password";s:15:"*token_prefix";s:1:":";s:18:"*format_callback";b:0;}s:7:"form_id";O:14:"FormItemHidden":18:{s:12:"*read_only";b:1;s:7:"*type";s:6:"hidden";s:7:"*name";s:7:"form_id";s:8:"*value";s:26:"login_user_form-1436465436";s:7:"*size";N;s:11:"*disabled";b:0;s:10:"*form_id";s:15:"login_user_form";s:8:"*print";b:1;s:8:"*label";s:6:"";s:14:"*placeholder";s:0:"";s:14:"*description";N;s:9:"*weight";i:2;s:9:"*parent";s:13:"primary_group";s:11:"*required";b:0;s:10:"*classes";a:0:{}s:9:"*dbname";s:7:"form_id";s:15:"*token_prefix";s:1:":";s:18:"*format_callback";b:0;}s:6:"submit";O:20:"FormItemButtonSubmit":18:{s:14:"*form_action";N;s:7:"*type";s:6:"submit";s:7:"*name";s:6:"submit";s:8:"*value";s:6:"Submit";s:7:"*size";N;s:11:"*disabled";b:0;s:10:"*form_id";s:15:"login_user_form";s:8:"*print";b:1;s:8:"*label";s:6:"";s:14:"*placeholder";s:0:"";s:14:"*description";N;s:9:"*weight";i:3;s:9:"*parent";s:13:"primary_group";s:11:"*required";b:0;s:10:"*classes";a:0:{}s:9:"*dbname";s:6:"submit";s:15:"*token_prefix";s:1:":";s:18:"*format_callback";b:0;}}s:9:"*action";s:14:"/demo001/login";s:9:"*method";s:4:"POST";s:8:"*title";s:0:"";s:9:"*submit";b:1;s:10:"*enctype";s:33:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded";s:13:"*title_type";s:2:"h1";s:12:"*db_values";b:0;s:10:"*gentime";i:1436465436;s:20:"*validation_errors";a:0:{}s:20:"*validate_callback";s:19:"login_user_validate";s:18:"*submit_callback";s:17:"login_user_submit";s:10:"*classes";s:0:"";}}}'
          WHERE SessionID = 'krd682btg38st6r5i0om1gpbj4'
```

The only warning I get from `mssql_get_last_message()` is:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'a:1:{s:5:"forms";a:1:{s:26:"login_user_form-1436465436";O:4:"Form":15:{s:10:"'.
```

However if I run the above query in SQL Server management studio It executes fine.

Obviously `SessionData` is just a serialized array. Other serialized arrays save just fine elsewhere in the system using the same syntax. What am I missing?

Since several comments requested it, here is how the query is generated: [See PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/cBaxf2m0)

Comment: Your PHP code is noticeably absent from your question.  

There are some special characters in your `SessionData` variable.  Depending on how you're building your `UPDATE` statement, it may be as simple as them not being properly marked up.  

Could you provide the PHP code building the `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: can you use the profiler to see how is the query that sql try to excute?

Comment: @LDMJoe The code that actually generates the statement is rather long. I used a custom made parameterized query class. But the code you see above is the result of echo on the final product. does that give you enough info or do you still want to see the rest of the code?

Comment: @EmilioGort The echo above is the query sql is trying to execute.

Comment: `Incorrect syntax near 'a:1:{s:5:"forms";a:1:{s:26:"login_user_form-1436465436";O:4:"Form":15:{s:10:"'.` - it could be that one variable or the resultant TSQL statement is being truncated somewhere, especially since the error is in the middle of that super-long string.

Comment: @danielson317 in the profiler you can see the query that SQL SERVER get, rather than the query that php produce

Comment: You probably need to escape your quotation marks in your PHP code.

Comment: @ChrisSteele If all I needed to do was escape quotation marks the query would have failed at the first `"` not the 8th. Also since double quotes are used all over the place in serialized string my other serialized strings would not be saving correctly but they are.

Comment: Looks like it is failing at the first * character.  Can you print out the query before it is executed?  Then you can see what is being sent to SQL Server.

Comment: That data is being truncated by mssql_query function. Never seen anything like it. If I instead manually paste the query into a string it works fine. Very confused right now.

Comment: @Greg You are already looking at the data being printed before I send it. I already said that. More info added as to how I generated that query and when it is getting printed.

Comment: Does a 'prepared query' work even with the 'null' byte in it? If you want to store data reliably but it will not be searchable then use 'base64_encode'.

Comment: @RyanVincent No it does not. I figured that out about 10min ago. lol. I posted my solution below.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out. Your findings are useful as regards SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally found the problem. Their were hidden characters in the serialized string. Specifically the null characters "\0" was being interpreted by sql server as a terminator to the query string. I updated my sanitize function to include this line after the single quote encode:

```
$string = str_replace("\0",'[NULL]',$string);
```

Fixed the problem right up.

Of course since this is occuring in a string I actually need to undo this after read

```
str_replace('[NULL]', "\0", $string);
```